# how to determine the sections for cell in UITableView - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cells, sections

im working on application that have search view,
the search view contain a tableView with 3 sections - i implement the section manually by

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0){
        UITextField *title = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
        [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [title setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        [title setText:@"videos"];
        return title ;
    }
    if (section == 1){
        UITextField *title = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
        [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [title setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        [title setText:@"documents"];
        return title ; 
    }
    if (section == 2){
        UITextField *title = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
        [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [title setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        [title setText:@"questions"];
        return title ; 
    }
}
```

now, all my data received with XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel>
    <title>documents</title>
        <item>
        <title>how to count the days</title>
        <link>some link...</link>
        <date>11/09/2007 16:45:00</date>
        <SupplierName>roei</SupplierName>
        <CategoryName>the omer</CategoryName>

      </item>

        <item>
        <title>research</title>
        <link>some link...</link>
        <date>16/05/2010 13:41:00</date>
        <SupplierName>eran</SupplierName>
        <CategoryName>shavoot</CategoryName>
      </item>

</channel>

<channel>
    <title> video </title>
                <item>
                <title>the end of holiday</title>
                <link>some link...</link>
                <date>06/06/2011 08:56:00</date>
                <SupplierName>dina</SupplierName>
                <CategoryName>shavoot</CategoryName>

              </item>

                <item>
                <title>bible</title>
                <link>some link...</link>
                <date>24/05/2012 10:00:00</date>
                <SupplierName>amir</SupplierName>
                <CategoryName>shavoot</CategoryName>        
              </item>

</channel>



        <channel>
            <title>questions</title>

                <item>
                <title>questions for shavvot</title>
                <link>some link...</link>
                <date>28/10/2008 13:31:00</date>
                <SenderName>אלי.ד.</SenderName>
                <CategoryName>holidays</CategoryName>
              </item>

                <item>
                <title>Shavoot</title>
                <link>some link...</link>
                <date>25/05/2008 01:01:00</date>
                <SenderName>amir</SenderName>
                <CategoryName>holidays</CategoryName>
              </item>


        </channel>


</rss>
```

as you can see- i have title with the names of the sections, but how should i determine the correct sections for the cells ?
im parsing all the data to one array and then getting it out using dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *object = [ResultsArrayDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

please help me, im after few hours of tries with nothing helpful in the internet so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

> im parsing all the data to one array and then getting it out using
>   dictionary:

Put the data for each section in its own array then use `indexPath.section` to determine which array to use.  For each section it will give you rows *for that section only* so you can use the `indexPath.row` to index into each of your arrays.

If you insist on keeping everything in one array, then you will have to maintain a count of how many of each type you have and then use that to figure out which array index you need.

In either case be sure to implement `numberOfRowsinSection:`.  If you're using multiple arrays then this will just be the array count for that section otherwise it will be the portion of your main array that is used in that section.

Comment: ok, im working on it.. i will let you know if i need any help. TNX